# Scrapy yeild items from multiple requests

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to yield items from different requests as shown here. If I add items = PrintersItem() to each request I get endless loops.. It I take it out other errors occur. Not sure how to combine yield request with yield items for each

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from ..items import PrintersItem
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class PrinterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'printers'
    start_urls = ['http://192.168.137.9', 'http://192.168.137.35', 'http://192.168.137.34', 'http://192.168.137.27', 'http://192.168.137.21' ]


    def parse(self, response):
            items = PrintersItem()
            token = response.xpath('//*[@name="CSRFToken"]/@value').extract_first()
            print(token)

            yield  FormRequest.from_response(response, formnumber=1, formdata={
                'CSRFToken' : token,
                'B55d' : 'password',
                'loginurl' : '/general/status.html'
             }, callback=self.postlogin2)


    def  postlogin2(self,response):
            items = PrintersItem()
            contact = response.xpath('//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[5]/dl[1]/dd[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/text()[last()]').extract()
            location = response.xpath('//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[5]/dl[1]/dd[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/text()[last()]').extract()
            items['contact'] = contact
            items['location'] = location

            yield Request(
            url = response.url.split('/general')[0] + "/general/information.html?kind=item",
            callback=self.action)

            for items in self.postlogin2(response):
                yield items

    def action(self,response):
            drum = response.xpath('//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[7]/dl[1]/dd[1]/text()').extract()
            items['drum'] = drum
            print(drum)
            printermodel = response.xpath('//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[5]/dl[1]/dd[1]/text()').extract()
            items['printermodel'] = printermodel
            yield Request(
            url = response.url.split('/general')[0] + "/net/wired/tcpip.html",
            callback=self.action2)
            for items in self.action(response):
                yield items

    def action2(self, response):
            tcpip = response.xpath('//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[4]/dl[1]/dd[2]/input[1]/@value').extract()
            items['tcpip'] = tcpip
            for items in self.action2(response):
                yield items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send `items` from `parse` to `postlogin2`, etc. then add it as `meta` data in `Request`

```
yield Request( ..., meta={"items": items})
```

and get it in other function

```
items = response.meta["items"]
```

and yield it only in the last function

```
yield items
```

Doc: [Request and Response](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html), [Request.meta special keys](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-meta)

---

```
class PrinterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'printers'
    start_urls = ['http://192.168.137.9', 'http://192.168.137.35',
                  'http://192.168.137.34', 'http://192.168.137.27', 'http://192.168.137.21' ]


    def parse(self, response):
            token = response.xpath('//*[@name="CSRFToken"]/@value').extract_first()
            print(token)

            yield  FormRequest.from_response(response, formnumber=1, formdata={
                'CSRFToken' : token,
                'B55d' : 'password',
                'loginurl' : '/general/status.html'
             }, callback=self.postlogin2)


    def  postlogin2(self, response):
            items = PrintersItem()

            contact = response.xpath('//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[5]/dl[1]/dd[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/text()[last()]').extract()
            location = response.xpath('//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[5]/dl[1]/dd[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/text()[last()]').extract()
            items['contact'] = contact
            items['location'] = location

            yield Request(
                #url=response.urljoin("/general/information.html?kind=item"),
                url=response.url.split('/general')[0] + "/general/information.html?kind=item",
                callback=self.action,
                meta={"items": items})


    def action(self, response):
            items = response.meta["items"]

            drum = response.xpath('//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[7]/dl[1]/dd[1]/text()').extract()
            items['drum'] = drum
            print(drum)

            printermodel = response.xpath('//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[5]/dl[1]/dd[1]/text()').extract()
            items['printermodel'] = printermodel

            yield Request(
                #url=response.urljoin("/net/wired/tcpip.html"),
                url=response.url.split('/general')[0] + "/net/wired/tcpip.html",
                callback=self.action2,
                meta={"items": items})

    def action2(self, response):
            items = response.meta["items"]

            tcpip = response.xpath('//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[4]/dl[1]/dd[2]/input[1]/@value').extract()
            items['tcpip'] = tcpip

            yield items
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks again