# Scrapy - Can not do multiple callbacks

Tags: python, scrapy

I am having problems going through multiple pages. Here is my class for scrapy code called quotes.

```
class quotes(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/?']

def parse(self, response):
    all_links = response.css('.nav-list ul li')
    for links in all_links:
        link = links.css('a::attr(href)').get()
        yield response.follow(link, callback = self.books_detail)

def books_detail(self, response):
    yas = {
    'title':[],
    'price':[],
    'availability':[],
    'category':[]
    }
    yas['category'].append(response.css('h1::text').extract())
    all_divs = response.css('.col-lg-3')
    for div in all_divs:
        link = div.css('.product_pod a::attr(href)').get()
        title = response.follow(link, callback = self.get_title)
        
        yas['price'].append(div.css('.price_color::text').extract())
        yas['availability'].append(div.css('.availability::text')[1].extract())
    yield yas


def get_title(self,response):   
    print('testing')
    title = response.css('h1::text').extract()
    yield {"title":title}
```

So I use a response.follow to goto function **books_details** and in that function, I again call response.follow to call **get_title**. I get the 'title' from get_title and the rest of the details from the main page.
I can **scrape** the information just fine from the **books_details** function and I can get the link of the title page just fine as well from the code line.

```
link = div.css('.product_pod a::attr(href)').get()
```

**But using the response.follow I can not go to the get_title function.**
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You do realize that you don't need to follow the link to the book page to get the book title, right? You can get it from the link's title attribute

Comment: maybe you need to use `meta=` in Request to send data from one parser to another and yield all data only in last parser. yesterday or two day ago was question for this problem but for http://quotas.toscrape.com.

Comment: Probably duplicate but I'm not sure: [Scrapy yeild items from multiple requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60385343/scrapy-yeild-items-from-multiple-requests)

Comment: BTW: you don't have to put books in one list but yield every book separatelly

Comment: BTW: you should create new dictionary for new book. Using the same dictionary in loop may create many results with the same data because they will use the same dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should yield request, not run it directly, and use `meta=` to send data to next parser

```
yield response.follow(link, callback=self.get_title, meta={'item': yas})
```

and in next parser you can get it

```
yas = response.meta['item']
```

and then you can add new values and yield all data

```
yas["title"] = response.css('h1::text').extract()

yield yas
```

---

See other example in [Scrapy yeild items from multiple requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60385343/scrapy-yeild-items-from-multiple-requests)

Doc: [Request and Response](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html), [Request.meta special keys](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-meta)

---

**Minimal working code** which you can put in one file and run as normal script (`python script.py`) without creating project.

There are other changes.

You shouldn't put all books to one list but yield every book separatelly. Scrapy will keep all results and when you use option to save in csv then it will save all results.

For every book you should create new dictionary. If you use the same dictionary many time then it will ovewrite data and you may get many result with the same data.

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'quotes'

    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        all_links = response.css('.nav-list ul li')
        for links in all_links:
            link = links.css('a::attr(href)').get()
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.books_detail)


    def books_detail(self, response):

        all_divs = response.css('.col-lg-3')

        for div in all_divs:
            # every book in separated dictionary and it has to be new dictionary - because it could overwrite old data
            book = {
                'category': response.css('h1::text').extract(),
                'price': div.css('.price_color::text').extract()[0].strip(),
                'availability': div.css('.availability::text')[1].extract().strip(),
            }

            link = div.css('.product_pod a::attr(href)').get()
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.get_title, meta={'item': book})


    def get_title(self, response):
        book = response.meta['item']

        print('testing:', response.url)

        book["title"] = response.css('h1::text').extract()[0].strip() 

        yield book

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #
})

c.crawl(QuotesSpider)
c.start()
```